# Can I re-login as the same unregistered user?

Tags: support, login, unregistered-users

I was having problems logging in to my account, and so I logged in as an unregistered user and asked a question.  I received a good answer and would like to give credit.  How do I login as the same unregistered user to continue with the conversation?

Comment: What do you mean by "I logged in as a guest"?..

Comment: @nicael unregistered user.

Comment: @Unihedron well, I started with "non registered" then realized it's actually "unregistered".